# Show error object:Object in get data

Tags: javascript, object

When I try to paging with JavaScript, I get the error `[object:Object]`. This is my code :

```
function onGetData(page)
        {
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Html.Toyota().Page.GetActionUrl("onGetBisa")",
            data: { 
                Display: $("#cbodisplay").val(),
                Page:page,
                mat_no : $("#txtMatNoC").val(),
                mat_desc : $("#txtMatDescC").val(),
                uom : $("#txtUOMC").val(),
                mrp_type: $("#txtMRPTypeC").val(),
                re_order_method : $("#txtReOrdMetC").val(),
                mrp_flag : $("#cbMRPFlagC").val(),
                valuation_class : $("#txtValuationC").val(),
                stock_flag : $("#cbStockFlagC").val(),
                asset_flag : $("#cbAssetFlagC").val(),
                quota_flag : $("#cbQuotaFlagC").val(),
                deletion_flag : $("#cbDelFlagC").val()
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#divtable").html(data);
                alert("sukses");
            },
            error:function(data){
                alert(data);
               }
            });
        }
```

I got error `object:Object`. Can anyone help me?

Comment: What is 'url: "@Html.Toyota().Page.GetActionUrl("onGetBisa ")"'? It looks like invalid Javascript.

Comment: Are you sure there are not any typo errors?  and this line in your code should be  url: "@Html.Toyota().Page.GetActionUrl('onGetBisa')",

Comment: yes i am sure there is no typo errors

Comment: Have you debugged in the server side code?

Comment: i dont know to do that :(

Comment: Rather than alerting error response, Do console.log(data.d) and post the console result.It might show some useful information in console.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get more info from error

```
error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
    alert(xhr.status);
}
```

Comment: now i got error 500, i dont know why/ anyone can help me -_-

Comment: @Html.Toyota().Page.GetActionUrl("onGetBisa"  didnt looks like  a good url  for ajax,

Comment: use console.log(data) and you can get more info from the console of your browser;  maybe is crossdomain, you have the JS in one server and the service in another domain

Comment: how i must do first? i dont know to do that, i am panic :(

Comment: are you the developer of the service you are trying to connect?